# Minimizing References with .NET Core csproj VS 2017 Tooling

Tags: msbuild, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, csproj

I have .NET Core class libraries I publish to NuGet. After upgrading them to VS 2017 csproj format, they have the following signature.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  ...
</Project>
```

Adding `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` seems to add references to a base set of libraries. However, as a library author myself, I probably want to only references a minimum set of references. Is that still true and if so, how can it be achieved?

Looking at the ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core projects, they seem to use `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` and do not individually select just the packages they need.

**Update**

I raised issue [dotnet/cli #5994](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/5994) on GitHub and @davidfowl said:

> The new guidance is to reference NETStandard.Library always as a package author.

However, he's not gone into detail as to why?

Answer (score 4):

You can set

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DisableImplicitFrameworkReferences>true</DisableImplicitFrameworkReferences>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In your .csproj. This tells the SDK to not reference NETStandard.Library or Microsoft.NETCore.App implicitly.